# WARNING: Category '' in library *any library* is not valid. Setting to 'Uncategorized'

Tags: library, arduino-galileo, ubuntu

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with arduino Galileo and the newest arduino IDE from arduino.cc and every time I compile I got this warnings with *any library* in place of EEPROM, SD, Wire, Wifi and a lot of others.

When I check the boards manager I got the following:

Invalid library found in /home/User/.arduino15/packages/Intel/hardware/i586/1.6.2+1.0/libraries/Wire: /home/User/.arduino15/packages/Intel/hardware/i586/1.6.2+1.0/libraries/Wire

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As sated above you need to "Edit or add library.properties to that folder so that you specify a valid category."

This link has some good info on the structure of the file: https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/wiki/Arduino-IDE-1.5:-Library-specification

From that link:

library.properties file format

The library.properties file is a key=value properties list. Every field in this file is UTF-8 encoded. The available fields are:

```
**name** - the name of the library
version - version of the library. Version should be semver compliant. 1.2.0 is correct; 1.2 is accepted; r5, 003, 1.1c are invalid
**author** - name/nickname of the authors and their email addresses (not mandatory) separated by comma ","
**maintainer** - name and email of the maintainer
**sentence** - a sentence explaining the purpose of the library
**paragraph** - a longer description of the library. The value of sentence always will be prepended, so you should start by writing the second sentence here
**category** - if present, one of these: "Display", "Communication", "Signal Input/Output", "Sensors", "Device Control", "Timing", "Data Storage", "Data Processing", "Other"
**url** - the URL of the library project, for a person to visit. Can be a github or similar page as well
architectures - a comma separated list of architectures supported by the library. If the library doesn’t contain architecture specific code use “*” to match all architectures
**dot_a_linkage** - (available from IDE 1.6.0 / arduino-builder 1.0.0-beta13) when set to true, the library will be compiled using a .a (archive) file. First, all source files are compiled into .o files as normal. Then instead of including all .o files in the linker command directly, all .o files are saved into a .a file, which is then included in the linker command.
**includes** - (available from IDE 1.6.10) a comma separated list of files to be added to the sketch as #include <...> lines. This property is used with the "Include library" command in the IDE. If the property is undefined all the headers files (.h) on the root source folder are included.
```

Comment: If you get this error for the FlexIO library installed with Teensyduino, this is because the author has entered a category "Utility" which is not accepted. I changed the category to "Timing" and the error is gone.

Answer (score 3):

Edit or add library.properties to that folder so that you specify a valid category.

Example of library.properties:

```
name=WebServer
version=1.0
author=Cristian Maglie <c.maglie@example.com>, Pippo Pluto <pippo@example.com>
maintainer=Cristian Maglie <c.maglie@example.com>
sentence=A library that makes coding a Webserver a breeze.
paragraph=Supports HTTP1.1 and you can do GET and POST.
category=Communication
url=http://example.com/
architectures=avr
```

Answer (score 1):

From: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/29336127-one-wire-library-still-in-v2-3-0-causes-useless-warning

> The Arduino library manager still defaults to v2.3.0, which causes the
>   IDE to raise the following warning on compile :
>
> WARNING: Category '' in library OneWire is not valid. Setting to
>   'Uncategorized'

Solution (In 1.6.12):

1. Sketch -> Include Library -> Manage Libraries
2. In the upper-right "Filter Your Search" box enter (without the quotes): "OneWire"
3. Click the "OneWire by Jim Studt, Tom P..."
4. Select version 2.3.1 (or newer)
5. Click "Install"